# How do I disable mapping of fields for Spring Data MongoDB documents?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I am using Spring Data to persist POJOs as documents in MongoDB via MongoRepository.  It looks like Spring is automatically persisting both fields and getters to MongoDB.

In general I would like it to only persist getters and never automatically persist fields.  I know about @Transient for one-off annotations, but would like to configure this as general behavior.

Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: Have you tried annotating the getter as transient and make the field private? That should work (however counterintuitive it is), if implemented analog to JPA.

Comment: Generally speaking all my fields are private and they are all getting persisted.  I can mark the private fields themselves as @Transient and that does prevent it from persisting.  However, the POJOs I am porting to MongoDB generally are only supposed to persist stuff from their getters, and the private field are not meant to be persisted.  Worse yet, I periodically get field collisions when one class inherits another and a private field has same name as a public getter in a super class.

Comment: Thats why I stated that annotating the getter instead of the private field might help... Or I am getting something wrong here...

Comment: Ha, I'm not sure.  You did say it might be counterintuitive so maybe I am missing something.  I'm understanding that if I mark the getter as Transient then it will not persist the results of the getter, which is opposite of what I want.  But in any case, I am looking for a configuration option at the system level or even class level which makes Spring ignore all the field members when persisting.  Otherwise it seems like I have to go into all my class and explicitly mark all the member variables as Transient.  Seems wrong/invasive??

Comment: Thanks for the help Markus.  Looks like I had the access concept backwards for Spring Data (see Konrad comments below).  It looks at fields only, not getters.  I think I understand what is going on now and why I was confused, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by writing your own custom Converters.

You state in your question that spring data mongodb persist **both**, fields and getters. To my knowlegde **only** fields are persisted. (See 11.1 in the docu: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.6.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#mapping-conventions (1.6.3 is the version shipped by spring-boot 1.2.6, but it is the same in older versions and 1.8.0))

or an short example:

If you have an Pojo like this:

```
@Document
public class MyClass
{
    private ObjectId id;

    private String foo = "foo";

    public String getBar()
    {
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

and a Repository like this:

```
public interface MyClassRepository extends MongoRepository<MyClass,ObjectId>
{
}
```

and an application code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException
{
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(NewClass.class, args);
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = ctx.getBean(MongoTemplate.class);
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    mongoTemplate.save(myClass);
    MyClassRepository myClassRepository = ctx.getBean(MyClassRepository.class);
    myClassRepository.save(myClass);
}
```

the following document is save (once by the template and then again by the repository:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("560b97edcb60110890ab7119"),
    "_class" : "sandbox.MyClass",
    "foo" : "foo"
}
```

So, the getter was not used for conversion of the MyClass object.

The same documentation as cited above shows you how to write your own Converter and how to register it to the MongoTemplate (section 8.10). You could write some code here that uses the declared getters of your class and maps them onto fields of your document.

Comment: Ah, right you are.  In Hibernate we always use "properties only" mode and disable field accessors.  So I have been thinking about this backwards with respect to Spring data, which was the source of my confusion.  Interesting... OK thank you for the help!